Запрос c оператором WHERE nestjs/graphql/typeorm?
Проект реализуется на vue/graphql/nestjs/typeorm.
В БД mysql есть таблица пользователей:
mysql> select * from user;
+------+---------+------------+---------+------+---------+------------+----------+------+------+
| name | surname | patronymic | isAdmin | area | user_id | phone      | password | role | note |
+------+---------+------------+---------+------+---------+------------+----------+------+------+
| John | Conr    |            |       1 | 1    |      17 | 9200138288 | 123      |      |      |
| Bob  | Glover  |            |       0 | 12   |      18 | 9305556666 | 1234     |      |      |
+------+---------+------------+---------+------+---------+------------+----------+------+------+

Nestjs:
user.entity.ts:
import { Field, Int, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
    type: 'bigint',
    name: 'user_id',
  })
  @Field((type) => Int, { nullable: true })
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  surname: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  patronymic: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  isAdmin: boolean;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  area: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  phone: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  password: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  role: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  note: string;
}

user.servise.ts:
найти пользователя, по полю "phone", используя оператор "where":
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { FindManyOptions, In, Repository } from 'typeorm';


@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User) private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  async findOneByPhone(phone: string): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.usersRepository.find({
      where: {
        phone: phone,
      },
    });
  }
}

user.resolver.ts:
import { Resolver, Query, Mutation, Args, Int } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { CreateUserInput } from './dto/create-user.input';
import { UpdateUserInput } from './dto/update-user.input';

@Resolver(() => User)
export class UsersResolver {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Query(() => User, { name: 'userByPhone' })
  findByPhone(@Args('phone', { type: () => String }) phone: string) {
    return this.usersService.findOneByPhone(phone);
  }
}

Фронт вызывает grqphql-запрос:
query findByPhone($phone: String!) {
    userByPhone(phone: $phone) {
        id
        name
        surname
        patronymic
        area
        phone
        isAdmin
        password
        role
        note
    }
}

с необходимыми данными:
{
  "phone": "9200138288"
}

Запрос отрабатывает со статусом 200, но возвращает все данные с null:
{
  "data": {
    "userByPhone": {
      "id": null,
      "name": null,
      "surname": null,
      "patronymic": null,
      "area": null,
      "phone": null,
      "isAdmin": null,
      "password": null,
      "role": null,
      "note": null
    }
  }
}

Выполняя msql-запрос напрямую, в терминале, пользователя возвращает как надо:
mysql> select * from user where phone = '9200138288';
+------+---------+------------+---------+------+---------+------------+----------+------+------+
| name | surname | patronymic | isAdmin | area | user_id | phone      | password | role | note |
+------+---------+------------+---------+------+---------+------------+----------+------+------+
| John | Conr    |            |       1 | 1    |      17 | 9200138288 | 123      |      |      |
+------+---------+------------+---------+------+---------+------------+----------+------+------+

Где моя ошибка? Почему grqphql-запрос возвращает null?
Заранее благодарен.
